# Update of SQL Server database fails

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, .net-4.0

Here's my code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class pinchange

    Private Sub btn_enter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_enter.Click

        Using _conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HOME-PC; Initial Catalog=csbanking; Integrated Security= true")
            Using _comm As New SqlCommand()
                With _comm
                    .Connection = _conn
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE USERLOGIN SET USER_PIN = @pin WHERE USER_LOGIN = @id"
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", txt_newpin.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Login.txt_id.Text)

                End With
                Try
                    _conn.Open()
                    _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Pin Change Successful")
        _1stpage.Show()
        Login.txt_id.Text = ""
        Security.msktxt_pin.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code success but fail to update Pin Change after I had add on "Where USER_LOGIN = @id"
what's wrong ?

Comment: Well, probably there's no user with that login id in the database. (Check case sensitivity, trailing spaces, etc.)

Comment: I put Public Shared txt.id.text on Login form , and it works on other form too ... how come it doesn't work in this form

Comment: I tried "UPDATE USERLOGIN SET USER_PIN = @pin WHERE USER_LOGIN = '"& Login.txt_id.Text &"'" and It doesn't work too

Comment: Check the value of `Login.txt_id.Text`

Comment: Don't use string concatenation. What you had first (" WHERE USER_LOGIN= @Id") was the correct way to do it. The string way leaves you wide open to a huge security issue.

Comment: I am now running ("WHERE USER_LOGIN= @id") and the code was successful , but database was not updated

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
    Using _conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HOME-PC; Initial Catalog=csbanking; Integrated Security= true")
        Using _comm As New SqlCommand()
            With _comm
                .Connection = _conn
                .CommandText = "UPDATE USERLOGIN SET USER_PIN = @pin WHERE USER_LOGIN = @id"
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@pin", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_newpin.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_id.Text

            End With
            Try
                _conn.Open()
                _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Pin Change Successful")
    _1stpage.Show()
    Login.txt_id.Text = ""
    Security.msktxt_pin.Text = ""
    Me.Hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solve my question

In my Login Form
public shared id as string = ""
then
id = txt_id.text

In my pin change form
Previous 
 .CommandText = "UPDATE USERLOGIN SET USER_PIN = @pin WHERE USER_LOGIN = @id "
then
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Login.txt_id.Text)

SOLVED
 .CommandText = "UPDATE USERLOGIN SET USER_PIN = @pin WHERE USER_LOGIN = @id "
then
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Login.id)

THANKS FOR EVERYONE WHOEVER PAY CONCERN AND HELP TO MY QUESTION
APPRECIATE YOUR HELP AND THANKS FOR UR KINDNESS AND HELPFUL VERY MUCH

Answer (score -1):

Everything seems to be good thus far.

It would be great if you can showcase your table schema.

May be passed parameter may have spelling issues or something.

Also, try to use stored procedure approach.

```
Create procedure dbo.[Usp_UserPin_Update]
@UserPin varchar(20) ,
@UserID int
AS
BEGIN
     UPDATE dbo.[UserLogin]
     SET User_Pin = @UserPin
     WHERE User_Id = @UserID

END
```

It should work fine.

Hope that helps!